# ssh login shows "No mail." twice

Tags: server, ssh

I was getting double motd message when logged in through ssh, google that and got rid of the motd, but there are still 2 lines with "No mail." after login, what is happening? How do I get rid of that?

```
E:\cmder
λ ssh 192.168.1.10 -l hub
hub@192.168.1.10's password:
No mail.
No mail.
hub@discovery:~$ uname -a
Linux discovery 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hub@discovery:~$
```